# How to send a error Message in Umbraco default popup?

Tags: umbraco

I'm hooking the publish event like this :

```
protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
{
   ContentService.Published += ContentService_Published;
}
private void ContentService_Published(global::Umbraco.Core.Publishing.IPublishingStrategy sender, PublishEventArgs<IContent> e)
{
 // My code , Send Error
}
```

When the user is "Saving and publish" a content i want to show the umbraco default error popup for errors with my custom error message.

Is it possible? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ContentService_Published` method I believe you can do something like:

```
e.Cancel = true;
e.Messages.Add(new EventMessage("Ouch!", "Better try that again but more gently this time!!!", EventMessageType.Error));
```